# How to deal with integrated graphics driver bundled with chipset driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, chipset

I am preparing to do a fresh install of Windows 7 and I noticed a potential problem with the chipset driver.

My motherboard: GA-MA78G-DS3H (rev. 1.0) http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2800#sp

There is a chipset driver for my motherboard on Gigabyte's website labeled as "AMD Chipset Driver (include chipset\sata raid\vga driver)".

The "vga driver" part is what worries me as I suspect that this means that bundled with the chipset driver is a driver for Radeon HD3200 graphics card integrated on my motherboard. I am using a much better Radeon connected via PCI Express but while the integrated card is disabled on the BIOS level I'm worried that on a fresh Windows 7 installation when I install the chipset driver the drivers meant for the integrated card are going to get installed as drivers for my Radeon connected via PCI Express.

Am I correct in this assumption? And if the integrated video card drivers get installed will simply uninstalling them before installing the latest drivers for my actual video card fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have no problem at all with that, it happens with every modern motherboard (whose chipset graphics are from the same manufacturer as the additional card). Just install the chipset drivers and then  the ATI drivers. If you get the option, uncheck the chipset graphics drivers, but it's not necessary.

Comment: I'm assuming that if I don't get the option the best way of resolving the problem would be uninstalling the bundled drivers before installing the drivers for my additional card, right?

Comment: It is possible that the Catalyst Install Manager will already recognise the situation and offer the correct drivers. Otherwise, the only downside of keeping the chipset drivers is used up space. The onboard graphics will be disabled.